# WPF validation launched on focus gained

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml, idataerrorinfo

I'm developing a  `IDataErrorInfo` to validate the textboxes I have inside my application. I have the following code:

The .cs class to validate:

```
 public class UserInformation : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string _name;
    public string _surname;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public string Surname
    {
        get { return _surname; }
        set { _surname = value; }
    }

    public override string  ToString()
    {
        return Name + " " + Surname;
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (columnName == null) return string.Empty;
            string result = string.Empty;
            if (columnName.Equals("Name"))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_name))
                    result = "Name cannot be empty.";
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public string Error { get; private set; }
}
```

The .xaml:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Name="TextBoxName" 
        Style="{DynamicResource InnerTextBox}" 
        Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ValidationErrorTemplate}">
        <TextBox.Text>
              <Binding Path="Name" Source="{StaticResource UserInformation}" 
                      ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                 <Binding.ValidationRules>
                       <ExceptionValidationRule />
                  </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
         </TextBox.Text>
      </TextBox>
```

And the `ErrorTemplate`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationErrorTemplate">
    <DockPanel >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Grid Width="20" Height="20">
                <Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Tomato" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontWeight="Heavy" FontSize="8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"
                   ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=ErrorAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">X</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock Foreground="Tomato" FontWeight="12" Margin="2,0,0,0" FontSize="20"
                       Text="{Binding ElementName=ErrorAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="ErrorAdorner" />
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The code works fine when I'm typing. But **when the TextBox is loaded, the validation occurs too**. And I don't want it to happen when it gains focus, only when it looses it or I change the text (like the one published here).

How can I avoid the validation error to be considered on first TextBox load?

NOTE: Even if I set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to **LostFocus**, it is still making the validations.

Comment: I was in an opposite situation no so long ago. I wanted textboxes etc to validate at start, and it was not working because I was using ValidationRule  class.  The solution for me was to switch to IDataErrorInfo, maybe you should look at ValidationRules instead, because that does not validate until you actually dont start typing or lose focus.

Comment: Could you please post an example on what you did...? maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To acheive you goal you need to:

First, remove `ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"` on your Binding. As said in [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.DATA.BINDING.VALIDATESONDATAERRORS%29;k%28VS.XAMLEDITOR%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29&rd=true):

> Setting this property provides an alternative to using the
>   DataErrorValidationRule element explicitly

And we're gonna use it explicitly. Then use `DataErrorValidationRule` instead of `ExceptionValidationRule` for correctly working with `IDataErrorInfo` and data errors.

And last, we need to use some properties that this rule gives us:

```
<Binding.ValidationRules>
    <DataErrorValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="False" />
</Binding.ValidationRules>
```

[ValidatesOnTargetUpdated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationrule.validatesontargetupdated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on false will not trigger validation when target itself changes (i.e. on load). You can also play with [ValidationStep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationrule.validationstep%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property for additional control.

**Edit:**
Ok, I see that you need to skip validation on load **and** you need to validate on lost focus even if the value was not changed. Well, validation rules does not support that, because if the value was not updated, then no changed events will be called and no validation will occur, regardless of `UpdateSourceTrigger` setting. 
The easy way out is to emulate this functionality by adding `LostFocus` handler to TextBox itself:

```
 private void ValidatedTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     var txt = (TextBox)sender;
     txt.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
 }
```

If you need this for several TextBoxes, you can move the code to some static class. 
The same results can be achieved using [Explicit update source trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), wich can be a little bit more cleaner.

Comment: Now it's not validating on load, but it doesn't on focus lost!

Comment: Ok, I'm getting something. First time the fiels is empty, and when focus is lost, nothing happens. After that I write something and delete it. Then the 'LostFocus'  is activated and the validation occurs. But now I don't know why this happens...

Comment: @Sonhja, well, the thing is - if you don't change the value, it will not trigger validation on focus loss regardless of any settings and types you use. Please check my update about that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have any example atm, because I moved to what you have. But You will need to create a class which will Inherit from ValidationRule which exist in system.windows.controls, and then override Validate method.

Then your xaml textbox would look something like this instead

```
 <TextBox.Text>
<Binding Path="your binding here"    UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus" >
  <Binding.ValidationRules>
    <validationClass:yourRule/>  define this at the top of xaml page
  </Binding.ValidationRules>
</Binding>
```

You should be able to find examples on msdn, and here about validation rules